# split a text by ingoring values with quotation

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to split a text in a specific way,ignoring the commas in sub string when inside ""

```
text='ppr5007801780,https://www.jcpenney.com/p/alfred-dunner-womens-3-4-sleeve-tunic-top/ppr5007801780,JCPenney,58.0,28.99,"https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/JCPenney/DP0208201907032983M.tif?wid=350&hei=350&op_usm=.4,.8,0,0&resmode=sharp2",,81730320182,Alfred Dunner Womens 3/4 Sleeve Tunic Top,Closure Type:Pullover Head|Neckline:Collar Neck|Sleeve Length:3/4 Sleeve|Apparel Length:24.5 Inches,alfred dunner,3,5.0,Navy White,"Embroidered, Scalloped",,/d/women,Available,1572644741'
```

I have the above string which I would like to use the split(',') ignoring the the commas inside quotations (i.e get `len(my_list)`=19)

I tried using `my_list=text.split(',')` but I get 23, I am not sure on how to do it using regex or some other method.

any help is appreciated

Comment: [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: @OlvinRoght can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the csv module. In order to pass the csv.reader a string, you need to turn it into a file-like object, which can be achieved using StringIO.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
text='ppr5007801780,https://www.jcpenney.com/p/alfred-dunner-womens-3-4-sleeve-tunic-top/ppr5007801780,JCPenney,58.0,28.99,"https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/JCPenney/DP0208201907032983M.tif?wid=350&hei=350&op_usm=.4,.8,0,0&resmode=sharp2",,81730320182,Alfred Dunner Womens 3/4 Sleeve Tunic Top,Closure Type:Pullover Head|Neckline:Collar Neck|Sleeve Length:3/4 Sleeve|Apparel Length:24.5 Inches,alfred dunner,3,5.0,Navy White,"Embroidered, Scalloped",,/d/women,Available,1572644741'

f = StringIO(text)

list = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar = '"')
for r in list:
    print(len(r))
```

The csv reader allows you to specify a "quotechar" parameter, which I believe essentially solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(StringIO(text)).columns.tolist()
```

Comment: you should probably clarify you're using `pandas`

Comment: i don't think I should use such a big tool for this small thing

Comment: such a big tool? this is just the simpler solution but if you prefer to use csv, it is ok too